# how to write mysql query to laravel eloquent query using below date conditions?

Tags: laravel

I have a below query in mysql, how to convert into laravel

```
WHERE (c.start_date >= '" . $params['start_date'] . "' AND c.start_date <= '" . $params['end_date'] . "')
            OR (c.end_date >= '" . $params['start_date'] . "' AND c.end_date <= '" . $params['end_date'] . "')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Model::whereBetween('start_date', [$params['start_date'], $params['end_date'])
      ->orWhereBetween('end_date', [$params['start_date'], $params['end_date'])
      ->get();
```

---

Or:

```
Model::where('start_date', '>=', $params['start_date'])
     ->where('start_date', '<=', $params['end_date'])
     ->orWhere('end_date', '>=', $params['start_date'])
     ->where('end_date', '<=', $params['end_date'])
```

Notice that `orWhere` kind of restarts the query so you start another query after `or`.

Comment: What do you mean by "condition different"?

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereBetween`

```
Model::whereBetween('start_date', [$params['start_date'], $params['end_date'])
      ->whereBetween('end_date', [$params['start_date'], $params['end_date'])
      ->get();
```

**Or**

```
Model::whereBetween('start_date', [$params['start_date'], $params['end_date'])
      ->orWhereBetween('end_date', [$params['start_date'], $params['end_date'])
      ->get();
```

Comment: Please select this answer if it's help for you and give upvote this answer ... Thank you..@Sairam

Answer (score 1):

```
$model = Model::where(function($query) use($params){
       $query->where('c.start_date','>=',$params['start_date'])
              ->where('c.start_date','<=',$params['end_date']);
})->orWhere(function($query) use($params){
       $query->where('c.end_date','>=',$params['start_date'])
              ->where('c.end_date','<=',$params['end_date']);
})->first();
```